# Dojo: checking values in a dijit.form.ComboBox

Tags: combobox, dojo

Hey guys! I have a dijit.form.ComboBox that needs have value checking applied against it.
Specifically the box is below...

```
          <input dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox"
            store="xvarStore"
            value="[% xv %]"
            searchAttr="name"
            name="xvar_names_[% section_count %]_arg_[% loop.count %]"
            id="xvar_names_[% section_count %]_arg_[% loop.count %]"
          />
```

the [% ..... %] stuff are values from Template Toolkit.

Anywho, the point of a ComboBox of course is that you can select a value or put your own in and that functionality I am not looking to change. What I do need to do is pop up or somehow nag someone if they put a value in that not in the list.

Anyone have a clue how I might do this. I thought about an onBlur event but I'm still a little mystified.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.
Janie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to require that the user enter a value that is in the list, then you probably want FilteringSelect, not ComboBox.  FilteringSelect does exactly this.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html

I've contrasted these two widgets in a blog post:

http://kennethfranqueiro.com/2010/06/combobox-vs-filteringselect/

Comment: Ken! I assumed when I shouldn't have. FilteringSelect is EXACTLY what I needed. U get the good answer karma buddy! .. Janie

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [dijit.form.ComboBox](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.5/dijit/form/ComboBox) is probably the best place to start, but you have the right idea. The `onChange` or `onBlur` events seem the most appropriate, but you could also write a custom `validate` function that would nag the user if values weren't in the list.